# How to create test branches and release branches in mono repo project with independent versioning using Lerna

Tags: git, git-flow, release-management, lerna, monorepo

I have a mono repo project in javascript(Vue) with independent versioning using the Lerna tool. When I want to publish these packages to NPM, I have used `lerna publish` command. But if I want to publish a version only for testing, how can I publish the test version to the NPM using the Lerna.

My Project Structure Given Below

```
main_project
   | packages
       | package1
          | src
          | package.json
       | package2
          | src
          | package.json
       | package3
          | src
          | package.json
   | lerna.json
   | package.json
```

I want to publish these packages for testing and release separately using git-flow and Lerna

Comment: How are you generating your releases currently? Can you post the lerna publish command line arguments you are using? Also, it's important to understand how this is going to be executed, are you using a CI or the releases are done manually?

Comment: Actually, I didn't start yet. I want to know how to release this test and production version separately. For testing purposes, I'm using `lerna publish --no-commit-hooks` this command is used and I also planning releases manually for this first two-three times and then I will migrate it into the CI. Can you suggest a workflow for this?